# How to convert a different UTC format to PDT by an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

A system I am using provides UTC time in the following format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000".

What Excel formula could I use to convert this to a date and time format of: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 PST?

I'm a complete noob, and even finding similar questions didn't get me to figure out the proper syntax and make it work.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: That is going to depend on if the data is stored as text or a true date.  If you change the format to "General" does it change to a number or does it remain a date?

Comment: Theoretically whether it is a date or a string doing `=A1-Time(7,0,0)` should do it then format what is returned in the format you desire.

Comment: @Scott Craner thank you so very much! It is currently set as "General", it seems!

Comment: Why don't you submit it as an actual answer? I could accept it in a second as I tested it

Comment: @ScottCraner It says: "#VALUE!"

Comment: @ScottCraner shouldn't the fact that a date is also present before the time be factored in in the formula? Or does it account for that in leaving it alone?

Comment: can you post a photo of what you tried.  my guess is that there is something more in the string than just a date and time.  Like a `T` between the 2 and/or a `z` on the end.

Comment: What I enter: https://imgur.com/qxR1E5G

Comment: And what I receive: https://imgur.com/Pcg9jYO

Comment: And the raw string: https://imgur.com/5dmnUzS

Comment: @ScottCraner Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Are there spaces before or after.  I cannot test anything because it works for me.

Comment: the mf, yes, it did have _one_ space before it! How did you even notice???

Comment: in that case: `=TRIM(A1)-Time(7,0,0)` should do what you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner This works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: Can I accept it as an answer?